# Why do char and string data types show different results in C++ when equating the same text value?

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I have the following code in C++

```
            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;
            int main()
            {
            char x[]="hello world";
            char y[]="hello world";
            cout << (x==y) << endl;
            return 0;
            }
```

This returns the value 0 i.e. not true
However if I now repeat the same values with string data type then

```
            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;
            int main()
            {
            string x="hello world";
            string y="hello world";
            cout << (x==y) << endl;
            return 0;
            }
```

This returns the value 1 i.e. true which is correct 
i.e. the character data type does not equate properly while the string data type does, why is this so?

Comment: You are comparing two pointers in the first case.

Comment: because in the first case, `x` and `y` are interpreted as `char*` when comparing which effectively compares their first element's address. if you really need this, use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: You mean array of `char`, not `char`.

Comment: note that some compilers optimize storage when strings are equal, and you could end up with first test being true (Visual C++ used to do that). Your code is then working but not portable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: They can do that for string literals, but not for char arrays. If VC++ did that, it was not in compliance with the standard, since it would be saying that two distinct objects have the same address.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: that's a good point! duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the first case you are just comparing the pointers `x` and `y` i.e. the base addresses of the 2 arrays. Use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for comparing the 2 character arrays.

In the second case, the `string` datatype overloads the `==` operator and actually compares the content of the 2 strings.

EDIT:
Information on `==` overload http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

Comment: But `x` and `y` are arrays, not pointers. So something is missing here...

Comment: Yes, but in C/C++, arrays are inherently pointers which point to the base address of the contiguous memory space where the array elements are stored.

Comment: No, that's not a very good mental model! That leads to all kinds of confusion.

Comment: @juanchopanza Perhaps you can clear it up for me and OP too, what the correct way to think about this would be.

Comment: Arrays can decay to pointers to their first element in expressions such as binary `x==y`, but they do not have pointer type (see for example `sizeof(x)` vs `sizeof(char*)`, or try `char* z = &x;`.) So you're right that two pointers are being compared, the missing part is why.

Comment: I feel the answer to the why is that arrays are not primitive data types and hence they are decaying to pointers in the case of the equality operation.